# Translation of "raw milk"

Tags: selección-de-palabras, comida

How do I refer to raw (unpastuerized) milk in Spanish?

*Leche cruda* is the obvious translation, but I have learned that *cruda* and *raw* have some different uses and subtleties about them.

And I know I've been corrected before when I say "leche cruda"... I just don't remember what I was told to say instead (in fact, I think I've had different answers before).

Comment: I've never even heard it referred to as "raw milk" in English until I read it right here (-:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've always heard it as *leche cruda*, though according to Wikipedia it can also be *leche bronca*.

Answer (score 2):

*Leche cruda* is OK, in [this Linguee query](http://www.linguee.es/espanol-ingles/search?source=ingles&query=raw%20milk) you can also see translated to Spanish in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

the correct translation is `leche bronca`  in most of the countries as stated on [wikipedia](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leche) however it could be `leche cruda` as you stated, however from what you've posted you live in Guadalajara (Mexico) and there they call it leche bronca.

Comment: This is not true in Argentina (for example)

Comment: it is not an incorrect answer though, I edited it just for the sake of disambiguation

Comment: Also not true in Colombia nor in Peru or Chile

Comment: neither leche bronca nor leche cruda ? my answer has both of them.

Comment: @RandolfRincón-Fadul: [Leche cruda](http://www.google.com/search?q=leche+cruda+site%3Aco) is very common in Colombia. I agree that _leche bronca_ is rare in Colombia.

Comment: @JaimeSoto I was talking about leche bronca, I know about leche cruda. I'm Colombian ;)